# Detect specific function calls in the source codes with objdump

Tags: c++, parsing, call, objdump, addr2line

I need a way to detect places, where a specific function is called.
E.g.:

```
myPrint():
main.c, line 28
utils.c, line 89
```

The point is, I need only function calls, **not definitions or declarations**. And I need it not only for "simple" C-like identifiers, but even for class methods, functions defined in namespaces etc., because I'll use this program mainly for C++.

---

#### My attempts

1. [GTags](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj81_GOofDOAhVDORQKHY-mDuMQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fs%2Fglobal%2F&usg=AFQjCNGt7_iOZFDpMAXjodOOhhF4Udjh7Q&sig2=kKkBWnmhuY9MPeY790ILgg) - Detects identifiers pretty well, but there's no way to differentiate function calls from definitions etc.
2. [CScope](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidxNqVofDOAhUEwBQKHfdZAAAQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcscope.sourceforge.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNGpJlybwzB0luZVCV7Uh9sS_NHDsg&sig2=-iC71qW7O814uLpmw9PdoA) - good for C, but fails sometimes with C++
3. `objdump` + `addr2line` - described more in detail below

I'm now trying to use `objdump` with `addr2line` this way:

```
objdump --disassemble-all binary | grep 'nameOfFunction'
```

Output looks like this:

```
5834c3: e8 e8 79 00 00          callq  58aeb0 <_ZN7espreso14IterSolverBase24Solve_RegCG_singular_domERNS_10ClusterCPUERSt6vectorIS3_IdSaIdEESaIS5_EE>
58bef4: e8 57 45 00 00          callq  590450 <_ZZN7espreso14IterSolverBase24Solve_RegCG_singular_domERNS_10ClusterCPUERSt6vectorIS3_IdSaIdEESaIS5_EEENKUliE_clEi>
58bf43: e8 08 45 00 00          callq  590450 <_ZZN7espreso14IterSolverBase24Solve_RegCG_singular_domERNS_10ClusterCPUERSt6vectorIS3_IdSaIdEESaIS5_EEENKUliE_clEi>
58bf7c: e8 cf 44 00 00          callq  590450 <_ZZN7espreso14IterSolverBase24Solve_RegCG_singular_domERNS_10ClusterCPUERSt6vectorIS3_IdSaIdEESaIS5_EEENKUliE_clEi>
```

And then I take the number from the first column and try to get the physical location in a code like this:

```
addr2line -e binary 5834c3
```

Sometimes it finds the function call correctly, sometimes it finds something completely different (I guess some kind of reference etc.).

And so, my question is - is it possible to detect which findings are function calls? I see, that there is `callq` in the output, but I'm not completely sure it's only function call in the code.

Comment: Have you tried [clang-tags](http://ffevotte.github.io/clang-tags/)?

Comment: @Leon I haven't, but now, when I took a look at it, it seems, that it only looks for "references", which means definitions and calls, not only calls. Do you know, how to look for calls only?

Comment: It seems to annotate references so that you can distinguish between a definition and a call.

Comment: @Leon As we can see in [this example](http://ffevotte.github.io/clang-tags/#text-2-3-2) , `void display ()` is listed within references.

Comment: Yes, but the comment on the right hints that it is a definition (not in a good format, however).

Comment: All you want is the location (file/line/column) of function calls (method calls, constructors, destructors, overload operator invocations, ...)?  Nothing else?

Comment: @Leon Oh, I thought the comment is not a part of the output itself :-)

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, exactly. Nothing else is needed :-)